# Fire a (multi) curl request and don't wait for the response (PHP)

Tags: php, api, curl, httpwebrequest

I want to fire a set of PHP script (through multi_curl) and not wait for a response from the caller script (200 OK):

I have an aggregator that runs searches on social media network APIs asking them for messages. When it gets a response it fires up another search for messages that were earlier (paging). This can take quite a long time and I don't want to make users wait for this to finish.

I would like to be able to fire up a set of PHP scripts from one main script, if you will, in the background (multi_curl?) that will each take care of grabbing all these messages, each script will have its network and keyword to look on and for. I want the main script to just call these other scripts and then not wait for them to finish and just print out 'requests fired, running in background' or something of the sort. It will return JSON, so it would have to properly close and give 200 OK.

How can I do this? So fire some multi_curls and not wait for them to finish?

Comment: Hm, don't know about the `multi_curl`, but [gearman](http://www.php.net/gearman) could be a good solution if you can get it on your server (I personally use `supervisord` to get the workers running).

Comment: @Wrikken, Thanks for the suggestion. I can't however install extra's on the servers. The system I am building should run on most shared hosts (sadly), so there is no room for custom installations.

Comment: hm, a pity. Can you rely on cron jobs or not even that?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes, cron jobs are ok. I believe that PHP scripts run even when you close the connection to them (using curl). But I will have to test that theory before I try to implement it. Otherwise I will have to go with something like what Arctic Fire suggested which looks like a good solution (database based queuing that is).

Comment: indeed, database based seems feasible. I would seriously discourage getting the webserver involved for requests that are essentially not webrequests, keeping threads busy otherwise used to serve your customers. Letting (long running) cron jobs pick them up from a queue is not that hard. If you _do_ go for the webserver route, remember to use `ignore_user_abort`.

Comment: @Wrikken - Thanks that is sort of the answer I was looking for! 'ignore_user_abort' that is. I would execute a series of multi_curls to my scripts (that would normally be run by a cron-job). Then I'd just disconnect them from within the script I call them with. ignore_user_abort should make sure that the scripts keep running even when I disconnect the curls.

Comment: the webserver also has a say, `ignore_user_abort` is no silver bullet, and frankly, a webserver should not be tied up doing this. Certainly on shared hosts, the amount of children/workers/threads might be limited.

Comment: @Wrikken - btw, could you post your comment as an answer so I can rate it as the correct answer?

Comment: @Wrikken - correct. However it needs to be a solution that holds for the next 2-3 weeks max. After that we will build a more solid and sustainable solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not privy to your particular setup, but you might be able to create a single script that runs your PHP scripts in the background with a bash script like this:

```
nohup php /path/to/script.1.php &
nohup php /path/to/script.2.php &
nohup php /path/to/script.3.php &
```

The ampersand at the end tells it to run the script in the background. the "nohup" command tells it to ignore any hangup signal, ensuring the script will continue running even if the user logs out.

Comment: Good solution, although I might get in trouble when I have to do domain-specific things on one server.

Comment: This ended up being the essence of what I finally used as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PHP port of Ruby's delayed_job.

https://github.com/seatgeek/djjob

Comment: It looks good, I will give this a go if all non-database solutions don't end up working and building my own implementation takes too long. Thanks.